# Onde é que se usa "imagina" em resposta a um "muito obrigado"? Desde quando?

Tags: expressões, origem, regionalismo

A mim parece ser algo do final do século XX.  Já ouvi muito o uso de "imagina" dito por operadores de telemarketing, principalmente paulistas.  Mas também já ouvi de pessoas provenientes de outros estados.  O certo é que no Rio de Janeiro nunca ouvi um carioca da gema usar essa expressão. Ainda, não sei exatamente se é uma impressão minha, mas parece que é mais usado por mulheres.

Comment: Nunca reparei em quais dialetos usam o quê como resposta a agradecimento. Mas forçando a memória, consigo lembrar que muitos brasilienses usam *"imagina"* para enfatizar o "contra-agradecimento", principalmente em respostas longas e compostas (*"Não... Quê isso.. Imagina!"*). Por mim, um simples *"De nada!"* ou um minimalista *"Nada!"* já estão de bom tamanho.

Comment: @Seninha   Atualmente é muito usado por operadores de telemarketing ou centros telefônicos, de forma curta: "imagina".

Comment: Diz-se quando alguém lhe agradece por algo: "Muito obrigado por ter me ajudado" -> "Imagina! Não foi nada". Lembrando que o obrigado original selaria um pacto de obrigação de retribuir, e esse imagina é mais uma forma de deixar pra lá.

Comment: É muito frequente (embora recente) em Brasília. Usualmente encurtado para "magina". Acho que começou a "pegar" de uns dez anos pra cá.

Comment: *parece que é mais usado por mulheres* - ou isso é por que atendentes de telemarketing são na sua maioria mulheres?

Comment: @LuísHenrique   Sim, a maioria são mulheres.  Por isso o "parece".

Comment: Isso é utlizado no Sul do Brasil. Vendedores, prestadores de serviço...Vejo normalmente utilzado quando a uma relação comercial.

Comment: No Paraná também se encontra - junto com "Capaz!" (também SC), "Acha!", "Até parece!" - e com certeza **fora** do contexto de relações comerciais.

Comment: "Imagina" é uma expressão de surpresa. O qué? Ele não gosta de mim. Imagina!

Answer (score 6):

Um "imagina" seria como um "por nada", no sentido de querer tirar do outro a obrigação de retribuir o favor ou a gentileza. Sou mineira e escuto muito. É coloquial, não tem nada a ver com "estropiar" a Língua Portuguesa, que, aliás, não se resume à norma culta. Quer estropiar a norma? Escreva "por que" junto em uma pergunta

Comment: Gostei da tua atitude. viu? :)

Answer (score 2):

Em qualquer momento onde se deseja responder um "obrigado". Eu particulamente uso direto e vejo várias pessoas usando tambem (sou de SP).